# Interpret UInt64 dateData in .NET DateTime structure?

Tags: .net, datetime, windbg, sos

In looking at a DateTime struct in the debugger via SOS.dll, I see...

```
  0:096> !DumpVC 000007feed1ddff8  000000028036d890 
  Name:        System.DateTime
  MethodTable: 000007feed1ddff8
  EEClass:     000007feecbed6b0
  Size:        24(0x18) bytes
  File:          C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.  dll
  Fields:
                MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr            Value Name
  000007feed1e1158  40000d6        0        System.UInt64  1 instance 5246421159766325152 dateData
```

How can interpret "5246421159766325152" as a DateTime?  Is there a way I can create a DateTime from this value to get the human-readable version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
DateTime.FromBinary(5246421159766325152)
```

Comment: I do this so often I use a powershell one-liner to get a quick answer: `[System.DateTime]::FromBinary(5246421159766325152)`

Comment: Note that the DateTime value is a UInt64 (ulong).  `DateTime.FromBinary` takes an Int64 (long).  This means that you can get a value that doesn't work directly with DateTime.FromBinary.  I saw this value in one dump: 9859146799984130527

Answer (score 9):

`!Psscor2.PrintDateTime OBJADD`R or `!sosex.mdt System.DateTime DATAADDR`.

Answer (score 1):

If the Int64 value is in between [DateTime.MinValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue.aspx).Ticks and [DateTime.MaxValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.maxvalue.aspx).Ticks, then you can call the overloaded constructor for a [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2xf7zzk.aspx) taking an Int64.

Your particular value falls outside of this range though. As @Boo mentioned, you can use the static [DateTime.FromBinary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.frombinary.aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a simple way to look at it WinDBG itself using a script, you can then run it as simple as:

```
0:000> $$>a<e:\Scripts\DumpDate.txt 0000003692816498
```

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2014/10/23/how-to-display-a-datetime-in-windbg-using-sos.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Rip out The UTC flags and print it in human readable format straight from windbg commandline  (subtract 1600 years from result)

```
!filetime 0n5246421159766325152 & 0x3fffffffffffffff
```

**5/25/3612 09:12:13.893 (unknown)**